# How long does it take until php deletes the cached version of require_once()

Tags: php, require-once

a few weeks ago I discovered, that an code update didn' t take effect. Reason was that I was using `require_once()`. It seems, that `*_once` caches the file into some kind of storage.

I' ve switched to just `require()` as a quick solution, but now I' ve run into a situation where `require_once()` is the only option.

The file might change at some point in time (modified by an backend) and I wonder how long does it take to update the cache?

Or am I just experiencing some strange behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's such a cache on *_once() functions. Maybe it's another thing like memcache or APC that's keeping an outdated version of your file, but this is quite a strange behavior anyway.

Comment: Ok, so it' s not releated to php directly. Thx anyway.